# I'd like to compare value of each row with previous row in a table and if amount > previous amount then I want to print date

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is a sample data

```
id  due_date    amount
162 2018-09-15 00:00:00.000 75.00
162 2018-10-15 00:00:00.000 75.00
162 2018-11-15 00:00:00.000 75.00
162 2018-12-15 00:00:00.000 107.27
162 2019-01-15 00:00:00.000 107.27
162 2019-02-15 00:00:00.000 107.27
162 2019-03-15 00:00:00.000 107.27
162 2019-04-15 00:00:00.000 107.27
162 2019-05-15 00:00:00.000 107.27
162 2019-06-15 00:00:00.000 107.27
162 2019-07-15 00:00:00.000 107.27
162 2019-08-15 00:00:00.000 107.27
166 2018-09-01 00:00:00.000 75.00
166 2018-10-01 00:00:00.000 75.00
166 2018-11-01 00:00:00.000 75.00
166 2018-12-01 00:00:00.000 156.57
166 2019-01-01 00:00:00.000 156.57
166 2019-02-01 00:00:00.000 156.57
166 2019-03-01 00:00:00.000 156.57
166 2019-04-01 00:00:00.000 156.57
```

I want a resul like

```
id  due_date_updated    amount
162 2018-12-15 00:00:00.000 107.27
166 2018-12-01 00:00:00.000 156.57
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(amount) over (partition by id order by due_date) as prev_amount
      from t
     ) t
where amount > prev_amount;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `outer apply` :

```
select t.*
from table t outer apply
     ( select top (1) t1.amount as prev_amount
       from table t1
       where t1.id = t.id and t1.due_date < t.due_date 
       order by t1.due_date desc
     ) as prev
where t.amount > prev_amount
```